# Tan help blocks overlap question editing area on Meta

Tags: bug, design

Firefox 34.0

When asking a question, the help rectangles overlap with the question composition area.

[image]

Comment: Confirm repro in Iceweasel 31.2.0 on Debian. Also on mine the yellow bar is moved to the left by 25px, so is pushed outside the text area.

Comment: Also happens in FF33.1.

Comment: Happens in Safari 7.1.

Comment: Happens in IE11, too!

Comment: Happens in Chrome 39.0.2171.71 Also

Comment: Happens in Mozilla SeaMonkey 2.30 and Konqueror 4.8.4 too

Comment: Happens in Firefox Dev Edition 35.0a2

Comment: And Happens in Chrome 38.0.2125.111

Comment: And firefox 45.0b3, same behavior as @James note above

Answer (score 7):

Decided to put the results in an answer in case the comments get deleted.

I will keep this updated as the comments come in.

```
Browser    Version
Firefox    34.0
Iceweasel  31.2.0
Firefox    33.1
Safari     7.1
IE         11
Chrome     39.0.2171.71
SeaMonkey  2.30
Konqueror  4.8.4
FF Dev     35.0a2
Chrome     38.0.2125.111
IE         11.0.9600.17420 (updated version 11.0.14)
```